# Android retrieve values ​from other class using Binding

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-databinding

Hello everyone I have a main activity that displays several Fragments

I add a value of type `int` to a TextView and I want to retrieve it in my Fragment

MainActivity :

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);

        binding.userBalance.setText(String.valueOf(1000));
    }
}
```

HomeFragment :

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    FragmentHomeBinding binding;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

        String currentBalance = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater()).userBalance.getText().toString();
        int currentBalanceInteger = Integer.parseInt(currentBalance);
        Log.d("Value", "Value of user : " + currentBalanceInteger);

        return binding.getRoot();
    }
}
```

As you can see I am doing a `Log.d`, I could notice that nothing was displayed in the console the value is non-existent.

I imagine that the problem comes from the fact that the value is not added in the xml but in the Java, but I have no choice to go through Java.

**How can I retrieve a value using Binding?**

Answer (score 0):

This approach is not ideomatic, but you can try something like this:
`String currentBalance= ((Main) requireActivity()).getBinding().userBalance.getText().toString();`.